# Linux, how do I use sed to edit apostrophes?

Tags: linux, sed

So I need to edit a bunch of html files..  I've used sed before, in batch, but the problem I'm having is that my string of text to locate and replace both contain apostrophe's.  While you can change sed's delimiter simply by picking whatever you want, apparently you cannot do the same with the apostrophe that begins and ends the command...  Is there another way to do this?

I'm looking to find '_blank');" />   and make it something else..  Using @ as the delimiter I can change just about any portion, but I want to add more parameters to it, and thus need to be able to 'send' apostrophies.  Is there a way to do this or do I need to seek another command?  Again, many files, would prefer not to do manually.

Thanks,

151

edit:  I didn't put exactly what I wanted done because of the whole "don't ask for things to be done for you" aspect that these sites support, but I was asked to in comments, so essentially....

Looking to change

```
ALIGN=CENTER '_blank');" />
```

to:

```
ALIGN=CENTER '_blank', 'width=100%'); />
```

what I've tried:

```
find . -name "*.php" -print | xargs sed -i "s@'_blank');" />@'_blank', 'width=100%'); />@g
```

Of course in testing I'm not using the *.php, I'm just testing on one specific file.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: Pls take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command should be

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i 's/);"/, \'width=100%');/' {} \;
```

There is no need for a pipe with `xargs`: the `-exec` option will do exactly that for you; also `-print` is not needed.

The `'...'` separators protect the text to be changed from the shell; for this reason you need to escape (*i.e.*, to precede `'` with a backslash, `\'`) the apostrophe inside your substitution to tell `sed`: look, this is not the end of the `s` pattern, but a literal character which should be considered part of the pattern altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, and more importantly for the lesson and explanation!  Appreciate it!